# Error al insertar datos con tablas relacionadas (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, laravel-8

¿Alguien sabe que está pasando? Sigo sin comprender ¿Por que lo altera así?:

```
insert into `admin_admin_role` (`admin_a_id`, `admin_role_ar_id`) values (?, ?)
```

Debería de estar así:

```
insert into `admin_role` (`ar_role_id`, `ar_admin_id`) values (?, ?)
```

**Tablas:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Terminal:**
[image: Terminal]

**Admin_role** (Modelo):

```
public function admin() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin');
}
```

**Admin** (Modelo):

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin_role');
}
```

**AdminsSeed** (Seed):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\Admin_roles;

class AdminsSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run() {
    $role_admin = Admin_roles::where('r_name', 'admin')->first();
    $admin = new Admin();
    $admin->a_name = "Admin admin";
    $admin->a_username = "admin@admin.com";
    $admin->a_password = bcrypt('admin123');
    $admin->save();
    $admin->roles()->attach($role_admin);
  }
}
```

Comment: Puede deberse al nombre de tus tablas, en cada relación pasa como argumento el nombre de la tabla intermedia como string

Comment: Ya hice los cambios. Si resulto, pero... ¿Ahora como seria para las columnas? Acabo de recalcar que en cada modelo esta definido las columnas, llave primaria y otros datos.

Comment: No entiendo que duda tienes respecto a las columnas, explica mejor por favor

Comment: A que ya no quedó así: `insert into `admin_admin_role` (`admin_a_id`, `admin_role_ar_id`) values (?, ?)` si no así: `insert into `admin_role` (`admin_a_id`, `admin_role_ar_id`) values (?, ?)` Me refiero a como puedo cambiar el nombre de esas columnas para que quede ahora bien.